# Jitter using ConstantForce2D (relative) in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm currently trying to create a 2D plane game (a bit Retry like), and I just discovered an annoying 
problem : the plane motion has a lot of jitters (didn't saw it earlier because I didn't zoom enough to see it).

I'm using a ConstantForce2D on the plane to move, and the arrow keys (in FixedUpdate) to rotate the object. I tried change Interpolate mode to "interpolate" and "extrapolate", extrapolate is worse, and the first one works only when strictly moving on x axis (jitters when there's a small rotation). 
I'm quite stuck on this :/

Has someone found a solution on this problem?
(I wasn't sure if any code was needed)

Comment: Code please? You likely have forgotten (on Update()) to use ``force * Time.deltaTime``.

Comment: The force is done via the Component Constant Force 2D, so there's no code for the force :/